# Не видна таблица

Tags: postgresql

Захожу в postgresql:

```
psql postgresql://test:test@0.0.0.0:5432/test_db
```

Есть таблицы:

```
                    List of relations
 Schema |   Name   | Type  | Owner | Size  | Description 
--------+----------+-------+-------+-------+-------------
 public | addrobj  | table | test  | 20 GB | 
 public | socrbase | table | test  | 96 kB |
```

Получаю их с помощью команды:

```
\dt
```

Дальше, делаю [так](http://postgrest.org/en/v6.0/tutorials/tut0.html#step-1-relax-we-ll-help):

```
create schema api;

create table api.todos (
  id serial primary key,
  done boolean not null default false,
  task text not null,
  due timestamptz
);

insert into api.todos (task) values
  ('finish tutorial 0'), ('pat self on back');

create role web_anon nologin;

grant usage on schema api to web_anon;
grant select on api.todos to web_anon;
```

После этого делаю:

```
\dt
```

И не вижу новую таблицу. В чём причина?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По умолчанию показываются только отношения из схемы `public`.
Указывайте схему явно:

```sql
\dt api.*
```

Или, если хотите все отношения со всех схем:

```sql
\dt *.*
```